# VBA Excel code to change tab color after making a copy of a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automatically change the color a sheet tab once I right click and select move or copy and then copy sheet. My template tabs are set to stay red since it indicates staff not to make changes. Is there a way that once I copy the tab it will change to blue so that it doesn't have to be done manually?

I have tried many variation of the code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "BlankTemplate-UnknownEZ1(2)" Then ' Adjust "CopySheet" to the name you use for copying sheets
        Dim newSheet As Worksheet
        Set newSheet = Sh
        newSheet.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' Change the color as needed
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9291237 perhaps.

Comment: Have you ever considered just writing a bit of code to do the Sheet copying and tab color change?  Assign a key combo to it and you have a fast way for your users to copy a Sheet.  As long as you have a static point where the new Sheet gets added, this should be an easy fix.

Comment: Add this bit of code and assign it a key combo (Ctrl+Shift+T?)     Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=ActiveSheet
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index).Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Comment: Genius! I would have never even thought to assign it a key combo, but it worked. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 1):

Create an event for the workbook, on either SheetActivate or SheetDeactivate. Loop through all sheets in the workbook. Any sheets that aren't templates are colored blue. Since creating a new sheet, or copying one, activates it, the event will always trigger.

In `ThisWorkbook` code module, write:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "BlankTemplate-UnknownEZ1" Then
            If WS.Tab.Color <> RGB(0, 0, 255) Then WS.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This event will overwrite any manual color changes since it runs through every existing sheet in addition to the new ones. You could consider creating list of "old" worksheets when the workbook is opened, and have the macro skip coloring those sheets.

In `ThisWorkbook` code module, write:

```vb
Private OldSheets As Collection

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set OldSheets = New Collection
    Dim WS as Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        OldSheets.Add WS
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim OldWS As Variant, IsOld As Boolean
        IsOld = False
        For Each OldWS In OldSheets
            If OldWS Is WS Then
                IsOld = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not IsOld Then
            If WS.Name <> "BlankTemplate-UnknownEZ1" Then
                If WS.Tab.Color <> RGB(0, 0, 255) Then WS.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Automatically Change the Tab Color of Sheets Not in a List

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    
    ' The list (an array) of the names of the sheets
    ' whose tab color will never change.
    Dim Exclusions(): Exclusions = Array( _
        "Sheet1", _
        "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", _
        "Chart1")
    Dim NewTabColor As Long: NewTabColor = vbBlue
    
    Dim shIndex: shIndex = Application.Match(Sh.Name, Exclusions, 0)
    If IsNumeric(shIndex) Then Exit Sub ' it's a sheet from the list
    
    Dim ash As Object
    
    For Each ash In Me.Sheets
        ' IF the sheet name is not in the list...
        If IsError(Application.Match(ash.Name, Exclusions, 0)) Then
            ' ... and if the tab color was not already changed,...
            If Not ash.Tab.Color = NewTabColor Then
                ' ... change it.
                ash.Tab.Color = NewTabColor
            End If
        End If
    Next ash

End Sub
```

- The issue with the following simplification is that if you copy multiple sheets at once, only the first (the left-most) will get its tab color changed.

[image]

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

    ' The list (an array) of the names of the sheets
    ' whose tab color will never change.
    Dim Exclusions(): Exclusions = Array( _
        "Sheet1", _
        "Sheet2", _
        "Sheet3", _
        "Chart1")
    Dim NewTabColor As Long: NewTabColor = vbBlue

    ' If the sheet name is not in the list...
    If IsError(Application.Match(Sh.Name, Exclusions, 0)) Then
        ' ... and if the tab color was not already changed,...
        If Not Sh.Tab.Color = NewTabColor Then
            ' ... change it.
            Sh.Tab.Color = NewTabColor
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
```

event procedure. Apply your code in this event handler.

SheetSelectionChange is for all sheet when the `Selection` of any of the sheets becomes another  object on it.